# How to remove filtered element from dictionary?

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
var scores: [String: Int] = ["Alex" : 4, "Rocco": 5, "Britney": 3, "Chad": 2, "John": 5]

func removeStudent() -> [String: Int]{
   let filtered = scores.filter{ $0.value < 3}
   return filtered
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking, the code seems to work as expected?

Comment: just trying to figure out how after this function I can remove filtered pairs, and don't really get how I can do that((

Answer (score 0):

Your code filters your dictionary to those entries who's value is < 3. You want to remove those values from the dictionary instead? So rewrite your filter statement to select the items you want to keep instead of the ones you want to get rid of.

In that case, you need a filter closure that gives you the inverse (everything **but** the items you are currently filtering).

The inverse of `< 3` is `>= 3`. So rewrite your filter statement as:

```
func studentsToKeep() -> [String: Int]{
   let keep = scores.filter{ $0.value >= 3}
   return keep
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works!

Comment: Note that a function that operates on a global dictionary and always performs the same task is not all that useful.  Rather than writing a custom function, it makes more sense to just call `filter()` when you need it.  (The function can be replaced with a single call to `filter()`)